# Visual Studio 2005 C++ Application Wants To Run As Admin

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, uac, admin, manifest

I wrote a simple c++ application in Visual Studio 2005 but when I compile it, the executable wants to run as admin. I tried deleting the manifest but it still wants to run as admin. I am running Windows Vista Home premium. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the name of the executable file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows will ask you for the administrator password if the name of your executable "looks like" a name of a setup program. Name you executable `setup.exe` and you will be prompted for password every time you run it. What is the name of your executable?

Comment: The name was "patch program.exe", I changed it to "abc.exe" and it no longer wants to run as administrator. I did some testing and discovered that if the name contains "patch" then it automatically tries to run as administrator. Thank you alot because it is unlikley I would have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent these heuristics from guessing for you, put a manifest on your application. From Visual Studio 2005 it is harder than from Visual Studio 2008. I have instructions at http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/AddingAManifestToAVistaApplication.aspx that elaborate on those at http://blogs.msdn.com/cheller/archive/2006/08/24/how-to-embed-a-manifest-in-an-assembly-let-me-count-the-ways.aspx - these are for VS 2005, for C#, VB, and C++. If your app has an asInvoker manifest it will no longer elevate even if it's named Setup.exe or Patch.exe.